# nodejs require() fails when called from php script (linux)

Tags: node.js, require

I have this script, minimathjax.js

```
console.log('toto');
var mjAPI = require("/home/pi/node_modules/MathJax-node/lib/mj-page.js");
console.log('titi');
....
```

It works fine when called from console ('node minimathjax.js' in its folder).

But when I try to call it from a php file :

```
$string = 'node /home/pi/node_modules/MathJax-node/minimathjax.js';
$res = exec ($string);
echo $res;
```

I just get 'toto', indicating that the require() fails.

How can I solve that ? It worked when I wrote it in Windows, and fails on linux (raspbian).
Is it related with permissions ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ls` command for check file permission.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this : I had installed a deprecated package (MathJax-node has become mathjax-node), the new version doesn't fail in its require...

But I still don't understand why it works directly and doesn't work when called from php ????